# Фамилия "Смола", склонять или нет?

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Закончила 9 классов, фамилия Смола в женском роде никогда не склонялась. Перешла в другую школу и учительница по русскому языку стала склонять мою фамилию. Прочитала много правил, но есть ссылки, где учитываются традиции местных поселений или желание носителя фамилии. Как быть в этой ситуации? Конфликт с учителем происходит на каждом уроке:(

Comment: Видимо, ваша учительница не учитывает традиции местных поселений или желание носителя фамилии.

Answer (score 2):

Желание носителя или местные традиции - вещь второстепенная. Они имеют силу только при наличии весьма веских причин отойти от общего правила. К таковым причинам относится, например, неоднозначность восстановления исходной формы или возникающее при склонении неблагозвучие. Могу найти полный список, но не думаю, что это актуально. Ваша фамилия ни под один его пункт не подпадает. так что новая учительница права с точки зрения русского языка.

Answer (score 1):

Из статьи:Склоняем фамилии работников и так, и этак… А нужно по правилам
Тема: Кадры  Образование и карьера

С ситуацией, когда работник – обладатель нестандартной фамилии  заявляет, что он  «вообще не склоняется», сталкивался, наверное, каждый. Но помимо обид коллег, есть еще и вопрос деловой этики. Не ошибиться и корректно написать фамилию человека при оформлении документов или в деловой переписке – это очень важно. Надеемся, что наши рекомендации помогут избежать досадных недоразумений.

Начнем с того, что в подавляющем большинстве фамилии на -А/-Я имеют четкое славянское происхождение (не надо быть филологом, чтобы это почувствовать). Например: Сковорода, Суббота, Дубина, Сметана, Кваша, Морква, Галушка, Кочерга, Зима, Навка, Щербина, Вишня, Воля и т.д.
Такие фамилии СКЛОНЯЮТСЯ, ПРИЧЕМ И В МУЖСКОМ И ЖЕНСКОМ ВАРИАНТЕ.